# Writing without a negative indeceH

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When trying to write: 
[image] without negative indeces, I simply put the whole expression over 1, and turn the negative exponent 4 into a positive exponent 4, is this the correct way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"Put the whole expression over 1" doesn't change anything, since $x=\frac x1$ always.

However,

$$\left(\frac{3f-4}{5g+1}\right)^{-4} = \left(\frac{3f-4}{5g+1}\right)^{(-1)\cdot4} = \left(\left(\frac{3f-4}{5g+1}\right)^{-1}\right)^4 = \left(\frac{5g+1}{3f-4}\right)^4 $$

Comment: But..for other questions like this, the answer is pretty much just over 1 with the operator inversed, How did you arrive at your final answer, and how do I apply your reasoning to every other question similar to this?

Comment: @Athchrisismbudd: Are you confusing "$x$ over 1" with "1 over $x$"?

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. I just want to put the given expression without negative indeces. Sorry for being confusing.

Comment: @Athchrisismbudd: You keep talking about "over 1", but putting someting over 1 results in $\frac{\text{something}}{1}$, which is the same thing and gets you nowhere!